# return function value as entry text

Tags: python, tkinter

This code is working and print the date at python prompt. But I want to set it as a value of Entry input box. Because I want to allow the user to make changes to the date manually if he has selected the wrong date.

```
def onclick():
    cd = CalendarDialog(root)
    print cd.result
    #self.myentry.set(cd.result)


class newdemo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.wm_title("Calendar Demo")
        self.myentry = Tkinter.Entry(root, text="Choose date")
        self.myentry.pack()

        self.button = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Choose date", command=onclick)
        self.button.pack()

#    root.update()

root=Tkinter.Tk()
newdemo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I found this class here...

https://github.com/moshekaplan/tkinter_components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tkinter Entry widget does not have a `set` method. You can use `delete` and `insert`.
Do you want `onclick` to be part of the `newdemo` class? If so, you can use:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class newdemo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.wm_title("Calendar Demo")
        self.myentry = tk.Entry(root, text="Choose date")
        self.myentry.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(root, text="Choose date", command=self.onclick)
        self.button.pack()

    def onclick(self):
        cd = CalendarDialog(root)
        print cd.result
        self.myentry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.myentry.insert(0, cd.result)


root = tk.Tk()
newdemo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If not, you need to keep a reference to the class to be able to access `myentry`:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class newdemo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.wm_title("Calendar Demo")
        self.myentry = tk.Entry(root, text="Choose date")
        self.myentry.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(root, text="Choose date", command=onclick)
        self.button.pack()


def onclick():
    cd = CalendarDialog(root)
    print cd.result
    demo.myentry.delete(0, tk.END)
    demo.myentry.insert(0, cd.result)

root = tk.Tk()
demo = newdemo(root)
root.mainloop()
```